# Sass error when calculating with percent and pixels

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to be able  a responsive grid, that I can input my column and my padding value.

```
@mixin setColumnWidth($columns, $margin) {
$totalColumn: 16;
$totalMargin: ($margin*2)* $columns*1px;
$totalWidth: calc(100% - #{$totalMargin})/$totalColumn;
$columnWidth: $totalWidth*$columns;
width: $columnWidth;
margin-left: $margin;
margin-right: $margin;
float: left;}

.articleCard {
@include setColumnWidth(4, 16);
}
```

But output is here

> Error: Undefined operation: "calc(100% - 0px)/16 times 3".
>   on line 37 of Users/mac/Documents/Projects/LeoX/New Version/HTML/scss/_myvalue.scss, in mixin `setColumnWidth`

Comment: Is the error actually including the "times 3" as above?

Comment: I dont know, this is the first time i learn to write by sass, the output of VSCode tell me:


Compilation Error
Error: Undefined operation: "calc(100% - 0px)/16 times 3".
        on line 37 of Users/mac/Documents/Projects/LeoX/New Version/HTML/scss/_myvalue.scss, in mixin `setColumnWidth`

Comment: Because at the last time, i just calculate in percent unit, so i re-write to calculate between px and percent unit. Error happen when i save my sass file to compile

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following to calc the `totalWidth` as the problem is the $totalColumn outside the calc and also needs to be wrapped as below:

```
$totalWidth: calc((100% - #{$totalMargin}) / #{$totalColumn});
```